# What does "informal application letter" mean?

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, application

For an application to a Master programme, I am asked to send:

- a description of my study motivation on 2 pages
- an informal application letter

What does "informal application letter" mean? Is it something commonly asked for an application? I really don't understand what they want.

Comment: It's a letter in lieu of an application form. See Nate's response for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would interpret that as asking for a short letter that briefly states what you are applying for, your educational background, interests and goals, why you are interested in their   program specifically, and mentions anything else you'd like them to consider.

Comment: I agree with the above. I would interpret it as pretty much the same thing as a cover letter that you would normally send along with your application.